# Group first, 2nd, 3rd, etc posts by category terms

Tags: posts, wp-query

This is a weird one, and maybe impossible.

I have a design where each category has a certain style in the index. Everything is in a grid so that one category takes up two columns, another takes up two rows, and the remaining two one row and one column only. Works great until you account for the client possibly posting 3 times in a row in the same category.

I need a way to output the posts so the categories are always in the same place in the grid, regardless of other Posts postdates.

```
<category 1 - most recent post>
<category 2 - most recent post>
<category 3 - most recent post>
<category 4 - most recent post>
<category 1 - 2nd most recent post>
<category 2 - 2nd most recent post>
<category 3 - 2nd most recent post>
<category 4 - 2nd most recent post>
```

etc.

Any ideas welcome.

**UPDATE: per request for code tried.** I have a clunky start that's 3 separate queries with offsets, but the solution would need to work for an unlimited number of posts. I know this isn't the way to go, but hoping a little something in front of me would be less abstract and lead to a better idea.

```
<?php $cat_terms = get_terms('category');
            foreach($cat_terms as $cat_term) {
                wp_reset_query();
                
                $catQuery = array(
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'posts_per_page' => 1,
                    'order' => 'DESC',
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'category',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => $cat_term->slug,
                        ),
                    ),
                 );

                 $cat = new WP_Query($catQuery); ?>
                 <?php if($cat->have_posts()) {
                  echo '<section class="">';  
                    while($cat->have_posts()) : $cat->the_post(); ?>
            
                    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="entry">
                        <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    </div>
                    
                  <?php endwhile; ?>
          
              </section>
      
                 <?php } } ?>
    
            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
            
            <?php $cat_terms = get_terms('category');
            foreach($cat_terms as $cat_term) {
                wp_reset_query();
                
                $catQuery = array(
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'posts_per_page' => 1,
                    'offset' => 1,
                    'order' => 'DESC',
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'category',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => $cat_term->slug,
                        ),
                    ),
                 );

                 $cat = new WP_Query($catQuery); ?>
                 <?php if($cat->have_posts()) {
                  echo '<section class="">';  
                    while($cat->have_posts()) : $cat->the_post(); ?>
            
                    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="entry">
                        <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    </div>
                    
                  <?php endwhile; ?>
          
              </section>
      
                 <?php } } ?>
    
            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
            
            <?php $cat_terms = get_terms('category');
            foreach($cat_terms as $cat_term) {
                wp_reset_query();
                
                $catQuery = array(
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'posts_per_page' => 1,
                    'offset' => 2,
                    'order' => 'DESC',
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'category',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => $cat_term->slug,
                        ),
                    ),
                 );

                 $cat = new WP_Query($catQuery); ?>
                 <?php if($cat->have_posts()) {
                  echo '<section class="">';  
                    while($cat->have_posts()) : $cat->the_post(); ?>
            
                    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="entry">
                        <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    </div>
                    
                  <?php endwhile; ?>
          
              </section>
      
                 <?php } } ?>
    
            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Can you include your code? What have you tried so far? Remember, you need your question t be specific enough that you can mark an answer as the factually correct answer for all people who will ever have this question

Comment: Updated to include some rough ideas. All I have at the moment that works like I need it to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still trying to determine exactly ***why*** this works, but it works. Still refining it and will post updates, but feel free anyone to improve upon this. It was modified from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26856578/wordpress-query-order-by-date-and-alternate-by-category) post.

```
<?php
$a1 = get_posts(array(
   'post_type' => 'post',
   'posts_per_page' => '-1',
   'tax_query' => array(
       array(
           'taxonomy' => 'category',
           'field' => 'slug',
           'terms' => 'cat-1'
       )
   ),
   'fields' => 'ids' // only get post IDs.
));
$a2 = get_posts(array(
   'post_type' => 'post',
   'posts_per_page' => '-1',
   'tax_query' => array(
       array(
           'taxonomy' => 'category',
           'field' => 'slug',
           'terms' => 'cat-2'
       )
   ),
   'fields' => 'ids' // only get post IDs.
));
$a3 = get_posts(array(
   'post_type' => 'post',
   'posts_per_page' => '-1',
   'tax_query' => array(
       array(
           'taxonomy' => 'category',
           'field' => 'slug',
           'terms' => 'cat-3'
       )
   ),
   'fields' => 'ids' // only get post IDs.
));
$a4 = get_posts(array(
   'post_type' => 'post',
   'posts_per_page' => '-1',
   'tax_query' => array(
       array(
           'taxonomy' => 'category',
           'field' => 'slug',
           'terms' => 'cat-4'
       )
   ),
   'fields' => 'ids' // only get post IDs.
));
$count = 999;
$newArray = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
   $newArray[] = $a1[$i];
   $newArray[] = $a2[$i];
   $newArray[] = $a3[$i];
   $newArray[] = $a4[$i];
}


$wp_query = new WP_Query(array(
   'post_type' => 'post',
   'post__in' => $newArray,
   'orderby' => 'post__in'
));

if ($wp_query -> have_posts()):
   while ($wp_query -> have_posts()):
       the_post(); ?>

    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="entry">
        <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>


   <?php endwhile;
endif;
?>
```